# vertical align text inner div without line-height

Tags: css

I have this codes:

```
<div style="height: 100px;">Text Go Here</div>
```

I want to have vertical-align text inner this div.
but I don't want to use line-height for example below:

```
<div style="height: 100px; line-height:100px;">I don't want to use line-heigh</div>
```

because line-hight shoud be: line-height:20px;

how I can do this?!

tnx :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to handle it is to treat the div like a table cell:

```
<div style="display: table-cell; height: 100px; vertical-align: middle;">Text Go Here</div>
```

Comment: I tested table-cell but it not work correctly in this position.

Answer (score 2):

```css
div {
    display: table;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd
}
span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>Text Go Here</span>
</div>
```